# Earth has just received a message from intelligent extraterrestrial life. What could this message say to cause the most panic?

Tags: aliens, modern-age

The year is 2020, and scientists have just received a distinct signal coming from deep space. The frequency of the signal is far from the natural frequencies of stars and pulsars, and it is clear that there is only one conclusion for the signal's genesis: extraterrestrial life.

This conclusion is further supported by the content of the message, easily decoded, which strikes panic into the hearts of all humanity.

**What could this extraterrestrial message be to create the most panic and chaos in our modern-age?**

Comment: The wavefront of a false vacuum collapse is ten seconds behind this message. Nine. Eight. Seven. ...

Comment: Unless you define in the question how you are going to pick a best answer, this is heavily opinion based

Comment: "We voted for _______ in the 2020 U.S. general election!" It wouldn't matter which name you used, you'd freak out at least 150 million people and you'd be front-page in every newspaper planet-wide for weeks.

Comment: "Shh!  They are listening...."

Comment: @workerjoe, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236292?

Comment: @Matthew exactly! can you beat that?

Comment: "All your base are belong to us"

Answer (score 3):

***A few suggestions:***

- "This message is being relayed via FTL stations. A nearby star has gone supernova and your entire solar system will be destroyed in five years."
- "The (Daleks, or name your fictional evil aliens) were introduced to your world as a fiction story to prepare you, but they're coming too soon. We can't stop them. Good bye."
- "We are (equivalent to) Borg. Resistance is futile. You will be assimilated."

Comment: you got these from the comments of the question... -1

Comment: @fartgeek Those were MY comments, that I turned into an answer and forgot to delete.  Fixed.

Comment: Whoops lol nvm...

Answer (score 1):

It should be sort of eviction notice: "We are sorry, but in 5 years, we age going to fade your Sun. Prepare yourself."

Comment: Weird. I was just adding a comment, and I picked five years for the world to end as well.

Comment: Let's hope that's not an omen...

Comment: "Your planet is scheduled to be demolished to make way for a new hyperspace bypass" 